# django form twice on same template

Tags: python, django

I am creating a page with a lot of data entry. I need a part where I can have the same form multiple times in one template

so I have a models like:

```
class base(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class other(models.Model):
  base = models.ForeignKey(base)
```

and then in the template I need `base` once, and then I need multiple `others` (dynamically). As of right now, I do the templates something like this

```
<div id="div_id_name" class="form-group">
  <label for="id_name" class="control-label  requiredField">
    Name
  </label>
  <div class="controls ">
    <input class="numberinput form-control" id="id_name" name="name" type="number" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

The only problem is, with using multiple of the same form, names of the fields aren't unique so I don't know how to same each one seperate. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you needed to have the same form a known number of time, you could have it add prefixes, by passing it `prefix='something'` when you create it. The prefix will be prepended to generated field names.

But in your case, what you really have it a *set* of forms. Probably for editing a collection of similar objects. Django provides the `modelformset_factory` function for this, which you would use this way:

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory


OtherFormSet = modelformset_factory(Other)

# Creating an empty formset
formset = OtherFormSet()

# Creating a formset from a queryset
formset = OtherFormSet(queryset=Other.objects.filter(something='foobar'))

# Validating and saving
formset = OtherFormSet(request.POST)
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

See the full documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

---

Now, from your question I believe you are actually editing a Base instance, and a set of Other instances linked to that Base instance, right? That's a very common case, and Django offers direct support for it, with inline formset.

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

InlineOtherFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Base, Other)
formset = InlineOtherFormSet(instance=Base.objects.get(pk=1))
```

Again, the documentation is pretty clear so for more, I'll let you read it:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: This is a very complete response. I really appreciate it

Comment: I've been messing with this for a while, and I find the first part about ```modelformset_factory``` useful for presenting the initial empty template. How would I dynamically add another form though? For example, when I view the page source, the initial form has the id ```div_id_form-0-``` in HTML. How would I dynamically add ```div_id_form-1-```, ```div_id_form-2-```, etc.

Comment: Basically, you have the pattern right. Pass `extra=1` to the formset factory, it will output an additional empty form. Hide it with CSS, and then in your Javascript you can clone it and show the clone everytime you need a new form. Two gotchas though: **1)** your javascript must update the ids for every clone and **2)** the formset uses a hidden `management form` to keep track of how many forms are on the page. You must update that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a prefix to the form by doing:

```
mother = PersonForm(prefix="mother")
father = PersonForm(prefix="father")
```

I hope this can help you further!

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms